# Diamond invalid character

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm creating a html website using HTML, PHP and MySQL but on HTML appears some a diamond icon on characters with accent. There is some prints to help you out.

I set this meta too:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

HTML Page:

[image]

PHPMyAdmin:
[image]

PS.: This question is not a replication of other question! If it is please tell me the link because I searched the same question and nothing found!!!

Comment: Whats the mysqli connection look like?

Comment: This is because of the MySQL Server stored it in Latin and not in UTF-8. The problem is not in the PHP page or HTML. It's how MySQL Server saves the data.

Comment: And how i change from latin to utf8 because this is a remote mysql server and the company that hosts this server dont let edit config files only let import configs

Comment: I solve this by adding:
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Comment: See "black diamond" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831

Comment: The duplicate link can be found under `This question already has an answer here:`.